# How to connect Pymongo with ssh as Robo3T?

Tags: ssh, pymongo

I am trying to connect a remote mongo server with SSH and Pymongo. I use the python package **sshtunnel**. It works with Robo3T, but fails with pythons

It works with Robo3T:

[image: Robo3T settings one]

[image: Robo3T settings two]

This is my code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

MONGO_HOST = "localhost:27017"
MONGO_DB = "dbasename"
MONGO_USER = "username"
MONGO_PASS = "password"

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    MONGO_HOST,
    ssh_username=MONGO_USER,
    ssh_password=MONGO_PASS,
    remote_bind_address=('10.0.0.244', 22)
)
server.start()
client = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port) 
db = client[MONGO_DB]
```

The code stops at `server.start()` . This is the error:

> 'Could not establish session to SSH gateway'

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

MONGO_HOST = "localhost:27017"
MONGO_DB = "dbasename"
MONGO_USER = "username"
MONGO_PASS = "password"

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
  MONGO_HOST,
  ssh_username=MONGO_USER,
  ssh_password=MONGO_PASS,
  remote_bind_address=('localhost', 27017)
) 
server.start()
client = MongoClient(host= 'localhost', port=server.local_bind_port) 
db = client[MONGO_DB]
```